# Как запустить исходник с GitHub с нужными мне параметрами в коде python

Tags: python, python-3.x, github

Хочу запустить данный исходник с GitHub https://github.com/crinny/teleboost
Допустим я весь код с него поместила в один файл, ошибок нет. Главным исполняемым классом, как я поняла, является `class ViewCommand(Command)` В этом классе находится основная функция, в которую нужно передать параметры для дальнейшей работы. Если установить пакет 'teleboost', то для использования нужно выполнить команду `python -m teleboost view "ссылка на пост"` Мой вопрос заключается в том, как выполнить эту же команду, но непосредственно в исходнике, то есть в коде прописать ссылку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Запуск модуля из командной строки как `python -m teleboost view "ссылка на пост"` вызывает модуль [`teleboost/__main__.py`](https://github.com/crinny/teleboost/blob/master/teleboost/__main__.py):

```
from .cli import application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

Объект `application` инициализируется так ([`teleboost/cli/__init__.py`](https://github.com/crinny/teleboost/blob/master/teleboost/cli/__init__.py)):

```
from cleo import Application  # type: ignore

from .view import ViewCommand

__slots__ = ("application",)

application = Application()
application.add(ViewCommand())
```

Здесь [`cleo`](https://github.com/sdispater/cleo) - библиотека, отвечающая за обработку параметров командной строки. `Application` нас не сильно интересует, нужно смотреть [`ViewCommand`](https://github.com/crinny/teleboost/blob/master/teleboost/cli/view.py):

```
...

class ViewCommand(Command):
    """
        Adds views to а post
        view
            {url : Telegram post URL}
            {--p|proxies=?* : Proxies file(s)}
            {--c|count=? : How many views do you want to add?}
    """

    def handle(self) -> Optional[int]:
        ...  # Разбор параметров командной строки

        loop.run_until_complete(self.view(self.argument("url"), proxies_list, count))
        return 0

    @staticmethod
    async def view(url: str, proxies: list, count: int):
        channel, post_id = parse_telegram_post_url(url)
        viewer = TeleboostViewer(
            proxies=proxies, channel=channel, post_id=post_id, view_count=count
        )

        with yaspin(text="Adding views...").yellow.bold.dots12 as sp:
            c = 1
            async for result in viewer:
                sp.text = f"Adding views... [{c}/{count}]"
                if not result.ok:
                    sp.red.write(f"> {result.error} [{result.proxy}]")
                c += 1

            sp.green.ok("✔")
```

В методе `handle` происходит разбор параметров командной строки, потом вызывается метод `view` с полученными параметрами. [`yaspin`](https://github.com/pavdmyt/yaspin) - это просто прогрессбар. В самом сокращенном виде будет что-то такое:

```
from teleboost.view import TeleboostViewer


async def view(channel: str, post_id: int, proxies: list, count: int):
    viewer = TeleboostViewer(
        proxies=proxies, channel=channel, post_id=post_id, view_count=count
    )

    с = 1
    async for result in viewer:
        print(f"Adding views... [{c}/{count}]")
        if not result.ok:
            print(f"> {result.error} [{result.proxy}]")
        c += 1
    
    print("ok")


import asyncio

# Параметры: имя канала, id поста
#  (ниже пример для url `https://t.me/channel_name/123`),
#  список прокси, количество повторений
asyncio.create_task(view("channel_name", 123, [тут список прокси], 100500))
```

Comment: Хорошая работа, а я начал разбираться и заленился, решил, что можно проще :D

Comment: @gil9red спасибо) Я вчера начал смотреть, споткнулся об yaspin, было лень смотреть что это, забил. Сегодня посмотрел на ваш ответ, подумал, что это слишком читерно, решил разобраться до конца)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Можно через `subprocess` вызвать текущий интерпретатор и у него нужный модуль с параметрами.

Попробуйте:

```
import subprocess
import sys

url = 'ссылка на пост'
subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m", "teleboost", "view", url])
```